# Numba failing to compile with very strange message - seems like this should work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, jit, numba

I have a simple function that is failing to compile with Numba's @njit decorator:

```
@njit(fastmath=True, nogil=True)
def insert_into_array(array, pos, array_to_insert):
    start = array[0:pos]
    end = array[pos:len(array)]
    inserted = np.concatenate((start, array_to_insert))
    return np.concatenate(inserted, end)
```

It's failing with this message:

```
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Invalid use of Function(<function concatenate at 0x000001E88B04E8B0>) with argument(s) of type(s): (array(uint8, 1d, C), array(uint8, 1d, C))
 * parameterized
In definition 0:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 1:
    All templates rejected without literals.
This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function.
[1] During: resolving callee type: Function(<function concatenate at 0x000001E88B04E8B0>)
```

Note that the types failing on are `(array(uint8, 1d, C), array(uint8, 1d, C))` - basically trying to concatenate two simple 1d arrays.

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding what should I do to fix this since NumPy's `concatenate` function is listed as a supported function by Numba.

I'm on Python 3.7 and Numba 0.50

Any ideas on what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a function which does not benefit at all from being numba'd in the first place. Anyway, the first argument to concatenate should be a tuple, you cannot pass var args. Your last call is trying that.

Comment: Aaahhh, yes! thank you, I had not realized I missed the tuple there... if you want to move the comment into an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a function which does not benefit at all from being numba'd in the first place. Anyway, the first argument to `np.concatenate` should be a tuple, you cannot pass var args. Your last call is trying that.

Comment: There was also a recent SO that found that `concatenate` in `numba` doesn't work with a list argument.  It has to be a tuple.